# iPhone numeric keypad distorts page width of HTML page

Tags: html, css, iphone

I am working on a PHP script for submitting butterfly/moth records to a website. The website uses the Bootstrap template. One one part of the page there is a tabular list of two fields per row, one asking for the butterfly/moth common name and the other for the count (the number seen). When I tap one of the Count fields using my iPhone the numeric keypad appears but when it does it distorts the page. It stretches it slightly and shifts the display to the left. When I tap in the next species field it shifts the page back to the right but the width is still stretched so text that used to fit the page width no longer does.

Here is a much cut down version of my code which still experiences exactly the same issue

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-7 autocomplete">
        <input type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="CommonName" 
                name="species">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <input type="number" 
              class="form-control"
              inputmode="numeric"
              id="Count"  
              name="count"  
              min="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<div>
```

I have experimented with the number of columns used by each field but without success

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend reading [mcve] and [ask]. And look into posting the minimal generated code instead of the PHP

Comment: Whatever is causing this issue has nothing to do with PHP since that is on the server.  Make a code snippet with the button that looks like `[<>]` in the toolbar when you edit your question so that we can have some code that can run and reproduce this issue

Comment: Thank you @ChrisBarr - I have edited my question and added a larger snippet of code. Let me know if you need to see any of the includes

Comment: We need to see enough to be able to reproduce the issue you are having. Just that bit of HTML by itself doesn't really demonstrate your issue. I have edited your question to include a snippet which now links to the bootstrap CSS so we can actually run this code.  Now what you need to do is run it and see if this reproduces the issue you have described or not.  If you need to edit that code, when you [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76886439/edit) scroll down underneath the but blue button and click the link that says *"edit the above snippet"* and make changes in there.